# Heroku set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url

Tags: django, heroku, htmx

I have a django app using htmx for a form and it's hosted on Heroku with Gunicorn as application server. I am getting 403 forbidden when I try to submit the form and tried a few different settings from reading the Django 4 docs. The form works on my local but not on Heroku.  What else should I try so I can submit my htmx form with https on Heroku?

my template

```
  <form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken":"{{ csrf_token }}"}' class="modal-content">
     ...
  <script>document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}';)</script>
```

my settings.py

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.herokuapp.com'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://django-example.herokuapp.com','http://django-example.herokuapp.com']
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Response headers

```
csrftoken=GjeYwnfTwUGLzF7DSJWOoaJk1GHiSC3MffaLaornrd4ENDgKlokkHsyoIERTReB4; Domain=.herokuapp.com; expires=Mon, 06 Mar 2023 18:01:01 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure

! This attempt to set a cookie via a set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url
```

Heroku logs

```
022-03-07T18:59:13.184551+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting server
2022-03-07T18:59:16.297718+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-07 18:59:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-03-07T18:59:16.298014+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-07 18:59:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:28553 (10)
2022-03-07T18:59:16.298062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-07 18:59:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-03-07T18:59:16.301273+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-07 18:59:16 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2022-03-07T18:59:16.704678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-07T18:59:16.727786+00:00 app[web.1]: Loading *prod* settings...
2022-03-07T19:05:52.345118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/form/create/" host=django-example.herokuapp.com request_id=5dd291a1-8b64-4581-bf61-2ed51510b6bc fwd="73.15.11.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=288ms status=200 bytes=1855 protocol=https
2022-03-07T19:05:56.691042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/form/create/" host=django-example.herokuapp.com request_id=6f612024-c8f8-457a-9231-6e3d7776f3ae fwd="73.15.11.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=403 bytes=1656 protocol=https
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I removed CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE settings and it worked